# Undefined index on add to array

Tags: php, arrays

im trying to make my first class in php from an exmple

http://www.php.net/manual/en/keyword.class.php

What i have:

file cart.php

```
<?php
class Cart
{
  private $items; //items in our cart

  public function Cart()
  {
      $this->add_item("03", 0);
  }

  public function add_item ($artnr, $num)
  {
    $this->items[$artnr] += $num;
    echo "product added";
  }
}
?>
```

file index.php

```
    <html>
<head>
<?php
include_once('cart.php');
?>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

     $test1 = new Cart();

?>
</body>
</html>
```

but it crashes on the line

```
    this->add_item("03",0);
```

witht he error Undefined index: 03 in

I cant fix it, can some one help me?

Comment: The array key does not exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to check if that array key exists *before* you append to it. If it doesn't exist you need to create it first, *then* append to it.

```
  public function add_item ($artnr, $num)
  { 
    if (!isset($this->items[$artnr])) {
        $this->items[$artnr] = 0;
    }
    $this->items[$artnr] += $num;
    echo "product added";
  }
```

Comment: Thanks it is working now, kinda weard i thought it was a official tutorial ;)